# i get a message saying "Head is now at f33dc83" when i attempt to delete branch

Tags: git, gitlab

why can't i delete this branch using command "git checkout -d branch"?
I'm complete noobie in git so I'm having trouble getting this to work

this is what happens what I attempt to delete it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9AP6.png)

Answer (score 3):

You probably wanted to use `git branch -d` to delete your branch, instead of `git checkout -d`.

In a `checkout` context, `-d` doesn't mean *delete* but *detach*.

"detached" mode means that you have checked out a specific revision but you're not currently linked to a branch. It's implicit when the given revision doesn't have a branch on it. One uses "-d" to check out the content of a commit pointed by a branch name without actually jumping on this branch.